# How to get unique pairs of values from a stl set

Tags: c++, stl, iterator, set

I have a stl set of integers and I would like to iterate through all unique pairs of integer values, where by uniqueness I consider val1,val2 and val2,val1 to be the same and I should only see that combination *once*.

I have written this in python where I use the index of a list (clusters):

```
for i in range(len(clusters) - 1):
    for j in range(i+1,len(clusters)):
       #Do something with clusters[i],clusters[j])
```

but without an index I am not sure how I can achieve the same thing with a stl set and iterators.  I tried  out:

```
for (set<int>::iterator itr = myset.begin(); itr != myset.end()-1; ++itr) {
    cout << *itr;
}
```

but this fails as an iterator doesn't have a - operator.

How can I achieve this, or must I use a different container?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

How about something along the following lines:

```
for(set<int>::const_iterator iter1 = myset.begin(); iter1 != myset.end(); ++iter1) {
    for(set<int>::const_iterator iter2 = iter1; ++iter2 != myset.end();) {
    {
        std::cout << *iter1 << " " << *iter2 << "\n"; 
    }
}
```

This yields all `N*(N-1)/2` unique pairs, where `N` is the number of integers in your set.

As an aside: use a `const_iterator` whenever you iterate over a container without modifying anything, it's good style and might have better performance.

EDIT: Modified the code to reflect the suggestion made by Steve Jessop.

Comment: Although the questioner doesn't say so in text, his code indicates that he doesn't want to see pairs in which the values are equal. So maybe replace `iter2 != myset.end(); ++iter2` with `++iter2 != myset.end();`

Comment: Apologies I misread what you said.  I indeed don't want the same value

Answer (score 2):

You don't need to do `end() - 1` since `end()` is an iterator that points **after** the last element in the container.

The corrected code is:

```
for (set<int>::iterator itr = myset.begin(); itr != myset.end(); ++itr) {
    for (set<int>::iterator itr2 = itr + 1; itr2 != myset.end(); ++itr2) {
        // Do whatever you want with itr and itr2
    }
}
```

Comment: Small mistakes: both numbers are necessary and `itr2` begins one number too early.

Answer (score -1):

Put your data in a boost::bimap, then iterate it both ways, copying the results into a standard STL map which will enforce uniqueness.